Importance of Symmetry in Probability
I was watching these videos here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnWK7xYuy00 , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH2kATv49rc&t=416s. Here is my takeaway:
Suppose we have a 2 Dimensional Random Walk $(X_n, Y_n)$.
Let $(X_n, Y_n)$ be the position after $n$ steps. Then, for each $n \geq 1$:
$$
(X_n, Y_n) = 
\begin{cases} 
(X_{n-1} + 1, Y_{n-1}) & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{4}, \\
(X_{n-1} - 1, Y_{n-1}) & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{4}, \\
(X_{n-1}, Y_{n-1} + 1) & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{4}, \\
(X_{n-1}, Y_{n-1} - 1) & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{4}.
\end{cases}
$$
As I understand, Polya's Theorem shows that given an infinite number of steps, the 2D random walk is certain (i.e. Recurrence Property) to return to the origin (0,0) an infinite number of times (actually, an infinite number of returns to any point given infinite steps).
Here is my attempt to express this idea mathematically:
$$
P(\text{Return to origin}) = P(\exists n \geq 0 : (X_n, Y_n) = (0, 0)) = 1
$$
These videos show that this Recurrence Property is only possible for 1D and 2D Random Walks, but not for 3D Random Walks. However, I have the following question:
In the above example (i.e. for the 2D and 1D case), the probabilities are defined to be symmetric (i.e. equal probabilities of moving left or right). Suppose the probabilities are no longer symmetric (i.e. unequal probabilities of moving left or right) - does Polya's Theorem still apply? Are symmetric probabilities necessary for infinite recurrences to still happen?

No. For example, the probabilities are 0.26 for moving one step North or East, and the probabilities are 0.24 for South or West, then the process will drift arbitrarily far Northeast over time, so there will be a time after which the process never returns to the origin.

thank you! is it possible to prove this?

just to recap: if the probabilities are NOT symmetric, Polyas theorem does not apply. Correct?
